# Is $L=\left \{ wxw \,\,|\,\,w,x \,\in \left ( a+b \right )^{+}\right \}$ Regular?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

### Question

> Is $L=\left \{ wxw \,\,|\,\,w,x \,\in \left ( a+b \right )^{+}\right \}$ regular?

### My Understanding/Doubt

We can say that Language

> $L_{2}=\left \{ wxw \,\,|\,\,w,x \,\in  \left ( a+b \right )^{*}\right \}$ is regular

By making  $x=(a+b)^{*}$ and $w=\epsilon$

Based on above Understanding , i can say that $L$ is regular?

---

My regular expression will be-:
$L=a(a+b)^{+}a+b(a+b)^{+}b+a(a+b)^{+}b+b(a+b)^{+}a$
Am i right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When is a string of the form $a^*ba^*b$ in the language $L$, i.e., of the form $wxw$, for nonempty $w,x$?

Or, to be more explicit, what is the language $L \cap a^*ba^*b$?

Comment: your regular expression will accept $bb$ which is not in language-:$a^{0}ba^{0}b$ because $w,x$ are non empty

Comment: @laura It was a hint, not a solution.

Comment: sir am i right that $L$  is not regular?

Answer (score 0):

*The answer previously provided here is wrong. Counter example is $ab a ab$, see comment section below*

> Your conclusions are correct, but your regular expression also accepts the strings $aab$ or $abb$, which are not in $L$.
>
> $a(a + b)^+a + b(a + b)^+b$ accepts a string $s$ if and only if $s \in L$, so $L$ is regular.

Comment: "if and only if"? What about $ab\cdot a\cdot ab$?

Comment: @HendrikJan sir, so $L$ will not be regular ? I am very confused .Please help me out

Comment: My answer is wrong, see Hendrick's counter example. The regular expression I provided only accepts a subset of $L$. Apologies.